# DJANGO - Reduce amount of field in queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model Product with a lot of fields (~50).
I have a filter like :

```
sale = Product.objects.filter(id=2)
```

But this give me all 50 fields for id = 2, so I tried to add *only* to reduce the queryset size since I only need 2 fields:

```
sale = Product.objects.filter(id=2).only("Origin","Price")
```

Now I want to access to the price with *sale.Price* but I have the error

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Price'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) this does *not* return a *single* `Product` object, but a *`QuerySet`* of `Product`s. You thus can not use `sale.Price`, since it is not a single `Product`, but a *collection* of `Product`s.

You should use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) to retrieve a `Product` *object*. Since `.get(…)` will immediately query, you thus need to place the `.only(…)` clause in front:

```
sale = Product.objects.only('Origin', 'Price').get(id=2)
```